# can't obtain values from XML after etree.parsed()

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml

So I've parsed an xml file with `lxml`.

```
import from lxml import etree
In [5]: root = etree.parse(fileXml)
In [6]: root
Out[6]: <lxml.etree._ElementTree at 0x7f2fa63ae388>
```

As you can see, the object contains 115139 records ... or at lease that's my understanding ...

```
In [21]: len(root.getroot())
Out[21]: 115139
```

If I get the first one, I do see some of the fields I'm expecting from it:

```
In [11]: root.getroot()[0].getchildren()
Out[11]: 
[<Element {xmlapi_1.0}receivedOctetsPeriodic at 0x7f2fa815df88>,
<Element {xmlapi_1.0}transmittedOctetsPeriodic at 0x7f2fa5b99508>,
<Element {xmlapi_1.0}inputSpeed at 0x7f2fa5b994c8>,
<Element {xmlapi_1.0}outputSpeed at 0x7f2fa5b99408>,
<Element {xmlapi_1.0}timeCaptured at 0x7f2fa5b99348>,
<Element {xmlapi_1.0}periodicTime at 0x7f2fa5b99148>,
<Element {xmlapi_1.0}displayedName at 0x7f2fa5b99088>,
<Element {xmlapi_1.0}monitoredObjectSiteName at 0x7f2fa5b94f48>]
```

How can a I retrive, for example, the field `displayedName`...?

I have for example tried out the `attrib.get` without success:

```
In [35]: root.getroot()[0].attrib.get('displayedName').text
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-653606973e5d> in <module>
----> 1 root.getroot()[0].attrib.get('displayedName').text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This is an exctract from a file that I'm trying to parse:

```
<findToFileResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
    <equipment.SystemCpuMonStats>
        <tmnxSysCpuMonCpuIdle>78.38</tmnxSysCpuMonCpuIdle>
        <tmnxSysCpuMonBusyCoreUtil>21.61</tmnxSysCpuMonBusyCoreUtil>
        <timeCaptured>1587078916040</timeCaptured>
        <children-Set/>
    </equipment.SystemCpuMonStats>
</findToFileResponse>
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you share an example of your XML file (just an example, no need to share the 115139 elements, of course!)

Comment: I've updated the post with an example ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

So my problem is I'm dealing with xml files that have `namespaces`. To be honest I really do not know what a namespace in xml means. Nevertheless, this is my solution.

```
fileCpu = 'file.xml'
from lxml import etree
tree  = etree.parse(fileCpu)
root  = tree.getroot()
xmlns = './/{' + root.nsmap[None] + '}'

for i in root: 
    myValue = i.find(xmlns + 'myKey').text
```

I had to first identify the namespace and use it together with the intended `key` to obtain the desired value.

I don't know if there is another solution for this, but it's so far working ...

Answer (score -1):

For example take this xml: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml

```
root = etree.parse("path")

for object in root.findall('food'):
    name = object.find('name')
    price = object.find('price')
    calories = object.find('calories')
    table = {'name': name.text, 'price': price.text, 'calories': calories}
    #Here we changed all the names in the xml to "hi"
    name.text ="hi"
    print(table)

#Here we save the new xml
root.write("path.xml")
```

As output we will get

```
{'name': 'Belgian Waffles', 'price': '$5.95', 'calories': <Element 'calories' at 0x000002704243A368>}
{'name': 'Strawberry Belgian Waffles', 'price': '$7.95', 'calories': <Element 'calories' at 0x000002704243A548>}
{'name': 'Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles', 'price': '$8.95', 'calories': <Element 'calories' at 0x000002704243A728>}
{'name': 'French Toast', 'price': '$4.50', 'calories': <Element 'calories' at 0x000002704243A8B8>}
{'name': 'Homestyle Breakfast', 'price': '$6.95', 'calories': <Element 'calories' at 0x000002704243AA98>}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question. Please be specific in answering the question that was asked, following by a snippet/example.